# How do I run two different processes on Windows cmd from a python script?

Tags: python

I need to run two different processes that will be running on two different cmd windows concurrently. These process are started from a python script.
I tried this but it never worked.

```
import os

# first process
os.chdir("path/to/firstDir")
os.system("start cmd")

# second process
os.chdir("path/to/secondDir")
os.system("start cmd")
```

This script start the processes on different cmd windows but the second process start after the first has finished. I need both of them to run concurrently on two different cmd windows.

I'm on Windows 7 64 bit.

Comment: both processes run on the same cmd window, i need each to run on its own cmd window, different from starting script window

Comment: The cmd window opens twice with each having its path. Tested on Windows 8, Python 2.7.3. Is it that the cmd windows are overlapping each other? Do a ctrl + tab to see whether windows are opened or not.

Comment: isn't `os.system` blocking? .. I think you want `subprocess.Popen` ...

Comment: @Amani: Isn't Joran's comment helpful?